# How is the decimal separator in a `Locale` determined?

Tags: swift, decimal, locale, separator

I have this sample code:

```swift
let locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
print("Language code: \(locale.languageCode ?? "nil")")
print("Region code: \(locale.regionCode ?? "nil")")
print("Decimal separator: \(locale.decimalSeparator ?? "nil")")
```

Using `en_US` in this example (English as language and USA as region) makes the Locale’s decimal separator a `.` because this is the decimal separator in the specified region "USA":

**Language code:** en
**Region code:** US
**Decimal separator:** .

Using `Locale(identifier: "fr_FR")` (French in France) for `locale` makes the decimal separator a `,` (because this is how the do it in the region of France:

**Language code:** fr
**Region code:** FR
**Decimal separator:** ,

Using French (`fr`) for the language and the USA (`US`) for the region in the locale still gives me a `,` as decimal separator (which seems wrong because the decimal separator should not be determined by the language):

**Language code:** fr
**Region code:** US
**Decimal separator:** ,

The remaining combination would be `en_FR` which seemingly inconsequentially gives the decimal separator `,`:

**Language code:** en
**Region code:** FR
**Decimal separator:** ,

What is the decimal separator dependant on?

Apple’s documentation only says this:

> For example, for “en_US”, returns “.”.

(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/locale/2292886-decimalseparator)

How can I get a locale that is french in language but has a `.` as decimal separator? `decimalSeparator` is read only…

Comment: Why do you need such a `Locale`? If you want to set the `decimalSeparator` on ` NumberFormatter`, just set its `decimalSeparator` manually.

Comment: Locale(identifier: "fr_US") gives me a dot as decimal separator

Comment: @DávidPásztor In software development many of us want to automate things. This is why I do not want to do it manually ;)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson This is completely crazy! How did you achieve this? Try to enter `import Foundation; print(Locale(identifier: "fr_US").decimalSeparator)` here: http://onlineswiftplayground.run (gives me `Optional(",")`)

Comment: For me too but when I paste the exact same code into a Xcode playground I get a dot.

Comment: I also get the same behaviour if I create a NumberFormatter object and set the locale to fr_US, a comma is printed in the online playground and a dot in the Xcode playground

Comment: Interesting. So, for me it doesn’t matter which compiler and IDE I use (local, online, playground, project, whatever), it always gives me a `,` for `fr_US` (when I am expecting a `.`). So, if someone ever finds out more, I would be happy to know what is going on here.